# Color management tool for Windows

Tags: color

I am looking for a program that can help me to manage my preferred colors.
Sometimes I found some nice colors and I would like to be able to save them, to be able to use them later when I need them.

For example I like this green color `#006629` and its lighter version `#00913A`. Also I like this orange color `#FF6700` and its lighter version `#FF8500`.

So I am looking for a color picker (so the user can tweak the colors) that can help me to manage the colors, by making a list with the colors that I want to save, showing them in say 100 x 100 pixel squares and save them to text configuration file. Would be better if it would allow defining separate lists for cold colors, warm colors, bright colors, or whatever other category of colors the user wants to define.

Maybe there are also web apps helping to keep lists of colors and to tweak the colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whether it covers all your requirements, but you could have a look at my freeware tool ColorBug:

http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/colorbug

- It offers working with user defined color palettes.
- The palettes can be exported to plain XML and to other formats like GIMP or Adobe.
- You can find matching colors with the intuitive HSL system.

Comment: Great program, thanks! I can define various color lists (color palettes) and save them separately. I would like to suggest to add various ways to visualize the color palette - for example with bigger squares or arranged in vertical/horizontal bars, circles (rings) containing each other, etc. Also i think it's important to allow the user to give names to colors (instead of naming them with "Color 1", "Color 2", etc)

Comment: just tried out colorbug, nice find

Comment: @JoeJobs - Thanks for your suggestions. Renaming the colors is very simple, just select the palette entry, click the entry a second time or use the menu `rename color (Ctrl+R)`, and type your name.

Answer (score 1):

[ColorMania](http://www.blacksunsoftware.com/colormania.html)

The best choice for your suggestion is ColorMania, it has the most features of the bunch. There are many other 'color pickers' for windows like [Color Cop](http://colorcop.net/) and [Pickard](http://pickard.sourceforge.net/). Best of all, many of them have portable modes available from the devs.

Comment: Color Cop and Pickard have less features (they are some 10 years old also), and in ColorMania (from BlackSun, no?) I can't find how to create my own list (palette) of colors. ColorBug looks to me much easier to use.

Comment: true, i havent had the need to find more color pickers, colorbug is pretty complete O.o